# ¿Círculo responsive y con el texto en el medio en bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy tratando de hacer un circulo con un icono en el medio pero sin hacer el `width` y `height` fijos. En este momento tengo esto:

```css
.service {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 50%;
  background-color: #6D435A;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #FFFCF9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="service">
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer un círculo perfecto sin hacer los width ni height fijos? Y, ¿cómo poner el texto en el medio? Supongo que habrá un método más eficiente que hacer el padding: 50%...

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta/problema?

Comment: @pablolozano Acabo de editar poniendo la pregunta al final

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para centrar el contenido en tu círculo puedes utilizar flex.

```css
#circulo {
 width: 10rem;
 height: 10rem;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: red;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
}
#circulo > p {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="circulo">
  <p>Hola StackOverflow en Español.</p>
</div>
```

Sobre si hay una manera de hacer un círculo fijo sin height ni width, sí: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Ede/90/

Comment: Gracias compañero! :)

Comment: @dddenis el SO esta pidiendo usar Bootstrap. Creo que lo adecuado seria responderle con tal.

Answer (score 2):

Usando la clase `rounded-circle` en bootstrap, recortaras la imagen en forma de un circulo.
Luego usa los `%` para definir un tamaño equivalente a otro elemento (div, body...)

```css
.tamano10{
width: 10%
}
.tamano20{
width: 20%
}
.tamano30{
width: 30%
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7">                
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/abstract_vector_background_3_148511.jpg" class="rounded-circle tamano10" />
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/abstract_vector_background_3_148511.jpg" class="rounded-circle tamano20" />
                <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/abstract_vector_background_3_148511.jpg" class="rounded-circle tamano30" />                
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: y para los `width` existen en [Bootstrap 4 los helpers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/#content)

Comment: @aldanux el problema que tengo, almenos con los [w-25](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/#content), es que no acepta por ejemplo w-10 o w-30